# Select the right Network Adapter to change IP settings automatically

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that will automatically find the ethernet controller under
(Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection) and change it to the right IP settings and subnet mask regardless of the name of the network adapter. I'm trying to make it where customers don't see any of the command prompt and they don't have to type anything on it either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if client have multiple network adapters?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do. I'm trying to select one specific network adapter regardless of the name of the network adapter.

Comment: but which one from (possibly) multiple adapters?

Comment: I don't understand the question I'm sorry..

Comment: This may get you started in the right direction: [Change IP Address using a script](https://superuser.com/questions/361038/how-to-change-ip-address-using-script-on-windows)

Comment: I can change the IP no problem. So what I'm trying to do is that we have customers that need to use a specific DHCP server and the network adapter name needs to be DPIDHCP. Some customers IT guys go in and change the name and the software we load on won't work anymore. I'm trying to make a Batch file that will automatically detect which network card I want and change the name, IP, and subnet mask. But if I write a script and the name isn't the same on the network card then it won't work. I just need it to automatically find the network card and change the name back etc.

Comment: You are trying to 'find' network adapter and change its IP settings, so I understand in case of multiple adapter present, you want to SELECT one and perform requested action on this adapter. So my question is HOW (criteria) do you want select the adapter. If i understand wrong, than excuse my lack of english

Comment: Right now I've been just trying to select the network adapter by typing:

netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" source=static ^
      addr=192.168.22.19 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.22.1
netsh interface ip add dns name="Ethernet" addr=192.168.18.1
netsh interface ip add dns name="Ethernet" addr=8.8.8.8 index=2

just as an example. Something a long the lines of this.

Comment: I'm still not sure of your criteria to determine the right adapter, but maybe something like this: `%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe nicconfig where "Caption like '%Name of your Adapter%'" call EnableStatic (“1.2.3.4”), (“255.255.255.0”)`

Comment: It says "No Instance(s) Available.

Comment: @CaseyNeckar, I would use only part of the name as the Caption field may not be an exact match.

Comment: Says now Invalid Query
@ECHO OFF 

%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe nicconfig where '%Intel(R) I211%' call EnableStatic (“10.125.0.65”), (“255.255.255.0”)